# share services between webapp (angular2) and mobile app (ionic2)

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make an webapp and an app. I want to share services and class between this two application.

This is how my project is organized

```
/project
   /webapp
      /src
       /app
   /core
      /class
      /services
        test.service.ts   
   /ionic-app
```

I want to use the test service in the webapp and the mobile app. The service will contain all my request to the API. I have make an npm link to link the core to the other folder.

When I import the test service in the webapp I have this error .

```
No providers for http.
```

My service content

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getTest(){
        this.http.get('API-URL') ;      
    }
}
```

I  use the latest release of angular 2 with webpack.

Comment: You have to export it as a module and then import it into @NgModule of other app.

Comment: Why dont you have separated projects ? 1.API 2.Web 3.App ?